# EndTime and PatternEndDate properties in RecurrencePattern object of an Outlook appointment

Tags: .net, outlook, outlook-addin

I have realized this weird behaviour in Outlook Interops, that in the [`RecurrencePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.recurrencepattern) class, the [`StartTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.recurrencepattern.starttime) and [`EndTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.recurrencepattern.endtime) property only give you the correct time part of the pattern, and the year is set to an arbitrary year way in the past like 1601 or 1899. Where the [`PatternStartDate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.recurrencepattern.patternstartdate) and [`PatternEndDate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.recurrencepattern.patternenddate) properties give you only the correct date part of the pattern, and if the pattern has no end date, then the end year is set to 4500.

This has caused some confusions and bugs in various places of my project. So before I go fix all of them by just adding the the date part and the time part together to get the real date time, I just want to confirm if this is the expected behaviour or I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is what Outlook always did...

Comment: So a follow up question to this would be, that if I need to manually create this RecurrencePattern when I have a DateTime object in .NET, can I just do: pattern.PatternStartDate = myDateTime.Date; pattern.StartTime = myDateTime? Or is it better to make pattern.StartTime = new DateTime(1601,1,1).Add(myDateTime.TimeOfDay)?

Comment: It is better to set the Start on the appointment itself. The recurrence pattern will adjust itself appropriately.